# Testing an Angular.js controller without mocking factory with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a angular controller that contains a dataService factory. The problem is that I get the error TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'myScope.data.test')

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="../scripts/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../scripts/angular-mocks.js" />

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory("dataService", ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {
    var _test = function () {
        return "Hello world";
    };
    return {
        test: _test,
    };
}]);


var testController = ["$scope",  "dataService",
function ($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.data = dataService; // This is similar to a DAL
}];


describe('Tests my controller without mocks', function () {

    var myScope;
    var myDataService;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $httpBackend, $controller) {
        angular.module('myApp');
        myScope = $rootScope.$new();
        myDataService = $rootScope.dataService;

        $controller('testController', {
            $scope: myScope,
            dataService: myDataService
        });
    }));

    it('should say Hello', function () {
        expect(myScope.data.test).toBe("Hello world");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bootstrap your app with *angular.mock.module('myApp');* within the beforeEach method.

From the test name it appears you want to use the real service ("without mocks"). In order to do that you should omit the *dataService* property from the explicit call to $controller. It will wire the real instances.

Comment: Thanks for your help, here is the code that works
describe('Tests my controller without mocks', function () {

    var myScope;
    var myDataService;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $httpBackend, $controller) {
        myScope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('testController', {
            $scope: myScope 
        });

    }));